# How to filter all the rows that contain ''isolated'' nan values in a column in python

Tags: python, pandas, filter, nan

I have a column in a pandas dataframe where some of the rows have NaN values.

I would like to select the rows that satisfy these conditions :
- they are NaN values;
- they are directly followed OR are ahead of non-null values

For example, I would like to select the rows for which there is this nan value : 
input:

index | Col

...
1 | 1344
2 |  NaN
3 |  532
...

desired ouptut : 
2 |  NaN

But I don't want to select these nan values (as they are followed by a NaN value or are right after another NaN value) :

index | Col

...
1 | 1344
2 |  NaN
3 |  NaN
4 |  532

...

Any help would be much appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: In the dataframe that you have shown there are no consecutive NANs, could you create a dataframe with which we can understand what you want and say what would be the expected output for this dataframe?

Comment: I have just edited it!

Comment: please check my solution and consider accept if my solution works:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I show you how to do it with an example.On the one hand, [`Series.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) + [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) + [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) is used to group consecutive `NaN` values ​​through [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). Using `transform` you get a Boolean Series with `False` in those groups **that have more than one `NaN`**. the `AND` operation of this Boolean series with the resulting series of `df2['col2']. isna()` is the series we are looking for to perform the [`Boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and select those rows where there is NaN but not consecutively

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'col2':[np.nan,2,3,np.nan,np.nan,6,np.nan,8,9,np.nan]})
print(df)
   col1  col2
0     1   NaN
1     2   2.0
2     3   3.0
3     4   NaN
4     5   NaN
5     6   6.0
6     7   NaN
7     8   8.0
8     9   9.0
9    10   NaN
```

---

```
mask_repeat_NaN=df.groupby(df['col2'].notna().cumsum())['col2'].transform('size').le(2)
mask=mask_repeat_NaN&df['col2'].isna()
df_filtered=df[mask]
print(df_filtered)

   col1  col2
0     1   NaN
6     7   NaN
9    10   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much !